# Bootstrap 5 Responsive Audio Tag

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, html5-audio

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card mt-4">
        <div class="card-header">HTML5 Audio Player Example</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <audio controls>
            <source
              src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"
              type="audio/mpeg"
            />
            <source
              src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.ogg"
              type="audio/ogg"
            />
            <source
              src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.wav"
              type="audio/wav"
            />
            Audio not supported
          </audio>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make the audio tag in Bootstrap card 100% width of the parent element by bootstrap 5 classes? Adding `style="width:100%"` works but I want to know how is it done by bootstrap way.

Comment: There is no issue adding `style="width: 100%;"` to the audio element. Otherwise you can use `w-100` class (which does exactly the same). Or you can add `d-flex` class on the `.card-body` element and `flex-fill` on the audio element.

Comment: You are putting a closing slash on your HTML tags. Note that HTML does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. For example: [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element)

Comment: @Rob it is I think because of Prettier extension of VS Code. It auto adds closing slash when I save the file.

Comment: You would be correct. MDN has the same issue and wishes it could be removed but they are stuck with it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just try add `w-100` in class attribute of `<audio>` tag.

```html
<audio controls class="w-100"></audio>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card mt-4">
        <div class="card-header">HTML5 Audio Player Example</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <audio controls class="w-100">
            <source
              src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"
              type="audio/mpeg"
            />
            <source
              src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.ogg"
              type="audio/ogg"
            />
            <source
              src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.wav"
              type="audio/wav"
            />
            Audio not supported
          </audio>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```